# Why margin:auto is calculated different on chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a hard time debugging this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lofipehoqo/5/).

Given the following layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="container contenedor">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <div class="filler green">Green</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="filler orange">Orange</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="height"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.filler {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.filler.green {
    border: 1px dashed green;
    background-color: green;
}

.filler.orange {
    border: 1px dashed orange;
    background-color: orange;
}

.height {
    height: 100em;
}

.contenedor {
    padding: 0;
}
```

It happens in chrome that the .container.contenedor in a viewport of 1200px the margin-right is computed to -15px and the margin-left is computed to 0px despite the fact that bootstrap set this two properties to auto. In a viewport, like in my case, of 1298px, both margin are computed to 49px.

So far as I know, margin-left/right when are setted to auto, at the same time, is a common technique to center a element because the remaining space on the sides are equally splitted.

So, my question is, this behavior is a chrome's bug? Did I miss something with this properties. Could any explain. Also, if I removed .contenedor (which is that have padding:0) the problem disapper and the margin left and right are computed correctly, but I still don't understand.

Thanks.

PD, I'm not trying to fix the layout or the css, I just want to understand why is this happening.

Update: I forgot to mention, my chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

As Bootstrap's docs says (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), rows must be placed within a container and columns within a row.

You're placing everything inside a column. I've excluded the first col-xs-12, and it worked here (Chrome/Firefox and Ubuntu 14.04 too).

```
<div class="container contenedor">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="filler green">Green</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="filler orange">Orange</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi estevan, thanks for reply soon. I'm an aware about the bootstrap problem, but as I ask. I'm not trying to fix the layout, and by that I mean that bad place it class... I'm more concern, about the diffferent values that the margin are computing, because even with that class col-xs-12 wrapping the container I cant understand why margin-left and margin-right are computing diffent if both are assigned to auto.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap .row class takes a margin-right and a margin-left of -15px each , you need to define it as zero in your stylesheet and secondly please use the .col classes inside the row div itself not outside the row to grid structure. And still if you have a problems with div set a width of 90% and give a margin:0 auto; i have tried in the same version of chrome and it works well on windows os. Here the js fiddle

.container {`width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;`}

http://jsfiddle.net/xnwnprf2/

Comment: hi @sydonia, yes, I'm fully aware about the grid system, and that that first .col-xs-12 is not the right way to used the bootstrap. But as I mentioned, I'm not aiming to solve that problem (I mean, eventually I will, It's not something that I did, I'm trying to fix) what it troubles me, is that chrome is computing margin-left and margin-right different despite the fact that both are assigned to auto and it's doing in the case that I mentioned... from 1200px to 1216px,  but from 1217px start to compute the same... and finally lg breakpoint is >= 1200px